# Why is plymouth required?

Tags: boot, plymouth, dependencies

Why is plymouth so important that cannot be removed on ubuntu desktop 11.04?

It has priority *required* and `mountall` and `cryptsetup` depend on it.

I do not have really any need to remove it, but a friend asked, so I am just curious.

Comment: Cause everyone -needs- graphical boot animations?

Comment: @user606723 If you don't want graphical boot animations, remove the plymouth-theme-* packages.

Comment: @htorque I have this on ubuntu server! (That doesn't have any graphical UI)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As htorque noted in the comments, if you remove the plymouth-theme-* packages you will not have a graphical boot. Ubuntu Developer, Upstart author, former Canonical employee, and current Googler Scott James Remnant wrote in a [relevant bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/556372/comments/2) that "without them Plymouth merely regulates access to the system console in cases of filesystem decryption and error."

Ubuntu and Debain developer Steve Langasek adds in a message to the [Debian development mailing list](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2011/07/msg00349.html):

> One of these days I'll get around to writing that blog entry to set
>   the record straight on why plymouth is an indispensible component of
>   boot with any modern boot system, because when everything is starting
>   in parallel, you need something to handle I/O multiplexing to the user
>   on console.  So in a real sense, it *should* be a dependency.  Even if
>   you don't care about splash, you still need multiplexing.

Comment: It is not understandable why those two functionalities, "provides a graphical boot animation" and "regulates access to the system console in cases of filesystem decryption and error - multiplexing" should be gathered in the same package. Also, package description is very short and misleading.

Comment: I agree. I only provide the best answers that I came across in my own quest to understand. Hopefully Steve will write that blog post some day. It seems to me that it is really just a marriage of convenience as both are things that need to happen very early in the boot process (i.e. before the file-system is fully mounted and X is started).

Comment: The graphical boot animation and console multiplexing are *not* in the same package.  If you don't want the graphical boot animation, you can remove the plymouth-label package, which will take all the graphical themes out with it while still leaving plymouth installed.  But I'm not sure why you would want to do that, really.