# Plymouth failed. Disconnecting from

Tags: 13.04, plymouth

...Plymouth.

If Plymouth fails, and Ubuntu still runs as it should, do I need Plymouth?

What is Plymouth?

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is plymouth required?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54176/why-is-plymouth-required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation [Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth).

It is just the animation/loading screen from the beggining of ubuntu boot.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for :-) Thank you @adi